# Unsilence iPhone based on coordinated/automation

Tags: iphone, ios, shortcut, automation, shortcuts-app

I have my work phone with me all the time, and I am trying to find a way to set up a shortcut automation whereby it always stays silent, but once I am at work I want to unsilence the phone. Also, I do not want to schedule it because my shift hours alternate. Any Idea how I could get it done via the Tools or Actions app?

Comment: why tag macos? surely ios?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Apple's focus feature. By default you can find focus in the control center (swipe down from the top right corner) and it should have an option for a new focus, or you can customize/automate an existing focus. There should be an option to activate/deactivate based on a location. You might first need to set up your work location in your contact card. If there are multiple locations you might need to use multiple focuses or set up multiple locations in the focus's automation. You can configure what notifications and alerts you get from the focus's configuration.